# replaceWith does not replace old div

Tags: php, jquery

**What i am doing:**

I am appending a div with a form and some buttons.The two buttons are save and cancel.When save is clicked,i am posting the form and getting the response.I want to replace the old div that houses the save was clicked.

This is the html and jquery http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/vSnJJ/1/

I am using this php but the post data is not sanitized since its an example

```
<?php
/**
test if replaced item can post and be deleted
@move ---->next
*/
$sliderKey = $_POST['sliderKey'];
$sliderPosition = $_POST['sliderPosition'];
$sliderTitle = $_POST['sliderTitle'];
$sliderLocation = $_POST['sliderLocation'];
$sliderDescription = $_POST['sliderDescription'];
$uniqid = uniqid();
echo "<div class='krudItem' id='$uniqid'><form class='aj' name='itemForm' method='post'action=''><section><label>Slider Title</label><input type='hidden' name='sliderKey' value='$sliderKey'/><input type='hidden' name='sliderPosition' value='$sliderPosition'/><input type='text' name='sliderTitle' value='$sliderTitle'/></section><section><label>Slider Location</label><input type='text' name='sliderLocation' value='$sliderLocation'/></section><section><label>Slider Description</label><textarea name='sliderDescription'>THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT</textarea></section><button name='saveNew' class='saveNew' id='$uniqid'>save</button><button name='newCancel'>delete</button></form></div>";

?>
```

This is the entire jquery i am using

```
jQuery(function() {
function randString(n)
{
    if(!n)
    {
        n = 5;
    }

    var text = '';
    var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for(var i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    return text;
}


 $("#button").click(function () {
$("<div class='krudItem' id='xxx'><form class='aj' name='itemForm' method='post' action=''><section><label>Slider Title</label><input type='hidden' name='sliderKey' value='16'/><input type='hidden' name='sliderPosition' value='12'/><input type='hidden' name='clickedButton' value='initial'/><input type='text' name='sliderTitle' value='lorem'/></section><section><label>Slider Location</label><input type='text' name='sliderLocation' value='ipsum'/></section><section><label>Slider Description</label><textarea name='sliderDescription'>hello world</textarea></section><button name='saveNew' class='saveNew' id='buttonId' value='saveNew'>save</button><button name='newCancel'>cancel</button></form></div>").appendTo('.krudSpace'); 
});
//save new
jQuery('.saveNew').live("click",function(event)
    {
     jQuery(this).attr("id",randString(7));
    event.preventDefault();
     var contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
   data: jQuery(".aj").serialize(),
  success: function(data){
  var quoted = "#"+contentPanelId;
  jQuery(quoted).replaceWith(data)
  }
 });
 return false; 
 });
});
```

It works to some extent but the old div is not replaced at all but the response is appended below the old.

Comment: Instead of saving `contentPanelId`, you should be able to just save `this`. Currently you're translating the element into its ID and then translating it back.

Comment: I just realized jQuery(this).attr("id",randString(7)); sets the id of the clicked button and not the div.How would i set the id of the div?.

Comment: `jQuery(this).closest("div.krudItem")` should work.

Comment: jQuery(this).parent().attr("id",randString(7)); works and to retrieve the id var contentPanelId = jQuery(this).parent().attr("id");,it works as expected but stacks the divs with the new one on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making things difficult. Just save the parent itself:

```
var $p = jQuery(this).parent();
```

and do:

```
$p.replaceWith(data)
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle (it uses `error` rather than `success` because there is no PHP): http://jsfiddle.net/vSnJJ/2/.